# PHP Paypal IPN listener failing with multiple items only not individual items

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm getting a very weird problem with my IPN listener when processing multiple items in Sandbox mode.

I've tested with the IPN simulator and it works fine, and also with the cart it will be used for adding one product and it works fine, but as soon as I add two or more different products into the cart and process, the IPN listener fails without any errors in the log.

Paypal is receiving and sending back all the correct data, as I can see the transaction details in the test Sandbox accounts and also the debug data in the script.

It's based on the official IPN Paypal script, but with the addition of email notifiers that are sent out.

```
    <?php
    // CONFIG: Enable debug mode. This means we'll log requests into 'ipn.log' in the same directory.
    // Especially useful if you encounter network errors or other intermittent problems with IPN (validation).
    // Set this to 0 once you go live or don't require logging.
    define("DEBUG", 1);

    // Set to 0 once you're ready to go live
    define("USE_SANDBOX", 1);


    define("LOG_FILE", "./ipn.log");

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'localhost';  // Specify main and backup server
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'XXXXX';                            // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'XXXXX';                           // SMTP password

    $mail->From = 'XXXXX';
    $mail->FromName = 'XXXXX';
    $mail->addAddress('XXXXX', 'XXXXX');  // Add a recipient

    $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML


    // PayPal IPN posts transaction info to this script
    // Read POST data
    // reading posted data directly from $_POST causes serialization
    // issues with array data in POST. Reading raw POST data from input stream instead.
    $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
    $myPost = array();
    foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
            $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
            if (count($keyval) == 2)
                    $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
    }

    // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
            $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
    }
    foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
            if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
                    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
            } else {
                    $value = urlencode($value);
            }
            $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }


    // Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
    // Without this step anyone can fake IPN data

    if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
            $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    } else {
            $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    }

    $ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
    if ($ch == FALSE) {
            return FALSE;
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);

    if(DEBUG == true) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
    }
    // CONFIG: Optional proxy configuration
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);

    // Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

    // CONFIG: Please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path
    // of the certificate as shown below. Ensure the file is readable by the webserver.
    // This is mandatory for some environments.

    //$cert = __DIR__ . "./cacert.pem";
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);

    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
            {
            if(DEBUG == true) {        
                    error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            }
            curl_close($ch);
            exit;

    } else {
                    // Log the entire HTTP response if debug is switched on.
                    if(DEBUG == true) {
                            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
                            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);

                            // Split response headers and payload
                            list($headers, $res) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $res, 2);
                    }
                    curl_close($ch);
    }

    // Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
            // check whether the payment_status is Completed
            // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
            // check that receiver_email is your PayPal email
            // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
            // process payment and mark item as paid.

            // assign posted variables to local variables        
            $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; 
            $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; 
            $address_street = $_POST['address_street']; 
            $address_city = $_POST['address_city'];
            $address_zip = $_POST['address_zip'];
            $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
            $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
            $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
            $payer_email = urldecode ( $_POST['payer_email'] );
            $shipping = $_POST['mc_shipping'];
            $payment_date = $_POST['payment_date'];
            $num_cart_items = $_POST['num_cart_items'];

            //Redundant variables
            //$item_name = $_POST['item_name1'];
            //$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
            //$item_name1 = $_POST['item_name1'];
            //$item_number1 = $_POST['item_number1'];
            //$item_cost1 = $_POST['mc_gross1'];
            //$quantity1 = $_POST['quantity1'];        

            /*
     * Deduct VAT from a gross price
     * Using 20 VAT
     */
    $gross = $payment_amount;
    $nett = $gross - (($gross*1)/6);
    $nett = number_format($nett,2);
    // gives 0.XX due to rounding


    $table = "<table>
      <tr >
        <th colspan='2' scope='row' style='padding:0 30px'>
        <h1 style='color:#333366'>INVOICE </h1>
        <p style='color:#000'>Date added: $payment_date</p>
        <p style='color:#000'>&nbsp;</p>
        <h3 style='color:#333366'>Payment Details</h3>
        <p style='color:#000'>Name: $first_name $last_name</p>
       <p style='color:#000'>Address: $address_street, $address_city, $address_zip</p> 
       <p style='color:#000'>Payer email: $payer_email</p> 
       <p style='color:#000'>&nbsp;</p>
        <h3 style='color:#333366'>Product Details</h3>";
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $_POST['num_cart_items']; $i++) {
     $table .= "<p>".$_POST['item_name' + $i]."</p>";
     $table .= "<p>".$_POST['item_number' + $i]."</p>";
     $table .= "<p>".$_POST['quantity' + $i]."</p>";
     $table .= "<p>".$_POST['mc_gross_' + $i]."</p>";
    }       
    $table .= "<p style='color:#000'>Delivery cost: £$shipping</p>
        <p style='color:#000'>Net price: £$nett</p>
        <p style='color:#000'>Gross price: £$payment_amount</p>
        <p style='color:#000;font-size:11px'>VAT calculated at 20%  </p>
    </th>
      </tr>
    </table>";

    $mail->Subject = 'Your Order';
    $mail->Body   = $table;
    $mail->addAddress($payer_email, $first_name.' '.$last_name); 
    if(!$mail->send()) {
       echo 'Message could not be sent.';
       echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
       exit;
    }


            if(DEBUG == true) {
                    error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            }
    } else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
            // log for manual investigation
            // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages


            $mail->Subject = 'Invalid';
    $mail->Body   = $table;
    if(!$mail->send()) {
       echo 'Message could not be sent.';
       echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
       exit;
    }


            if(DEBUG == true) {
                    error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Is the IPN returning valid still with multiple items?

Comment: Yes still returning valid.

Answer (score 5):

I finally solved this. The issue was with curl setup.

Orders with multiple products are much longer than the orders with single products.

curl is set to send an extra header (HTTP/1.1 100 Continue) when the data is over a certain length.

There is a simple fix for this.

Add 'Expect:' as a value to the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER array.

So:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
```

Becomes

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Expect:','Connection: Close'));
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution!